# Json Result can't be binded to KendoUI grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I can't display in a kendo grid the data that I am returning from my Controller as Json Result.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PermitSearch(BptSearchViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var data = appService.SearchPermitInspection(viewModel);

        return Json(data);
    }
```

now from my View I am submitting the information using ajax

```
  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("PermitSearch", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions
  {
        HttpMethod = "post",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
        UpdateTargetId = "search-results-grid",
        OnComplete = "OnCompleteMethod"
  }))
  {
           ....
  }

<div id="search-results-grid"></div>
```

an the script with the OnCompleteMethod is below

```
function OnCompleteMethod(dataq, status) {
    if (status === "success") {
        $("#search-results-grid").kendoGrid({
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "jobname",
                    title: "Job Type"
                },
            dataSource: {
                data: {
                    "items" : dataq
                },
                schema: {
                    data: "items"
                }
            },
            groupable: true,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes: true,
                buttonCount: 5
            },
            noRecords: {
                template: "No data available on current page. Current page is: #=this.dataSource.page()#"
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and the data that I am returning looks like this after I call the controller

```
[
  {
    "jobname": "job1"
  },
  {
    "jobname": "job2"
  }
]
```

The examples that I have been seeing that works are using the keys of the object inside the array without quotes, like this, but I can't find any transformation that I can apply to pass the json data to the grid in that way.

```
 [
      {
        jobname: "job1"
      },
      {
        jobname: "job2"
      }
 ]
```

You can see the response of the browser here

[image]
What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What does `dataq` and `status` contain when entering the `OnCompleteMethod` function?

Comment: you have defined the schema to look for data in a property called "items" but I don't see that as a property in the JSON sample, try returning an array called "items" and it should bind.

Comment: @StephenByrne I tried your approach but still doesn't work, if I copy and paste the data that I am seeing on my response directly as part of the script I am able to see the elements on it, but passing as parameter of the function seems to be in a different format as I updated on my question but the weird thing is that even pasting the code with doble quotes inside the script seems to work as well, any help on this?

Comment: @Heinrich - can you try changing `dataSource: {data: { "items" : dataq}},` to `dataSource: {data: dataq}` because iirc, when you're using a dataSource like that, there is no "items" property, you just put the data array directly into the "data" property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `dataq` is [local data](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/datasource/overview#to-local-data) which contains an object array with all the items required in the grid, try using the grid definition:

```
$("#search-results-grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [{
        field: "jobname",
        title: "Job Type"
    }],
    dataSource: {
        data: JSON.parse(dataq),
        pageSize: 10               
    },
    groupable: true,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        pageSizes: true,
        buttonCount: 5
    },
    noRecords: {
        template: "No data available on current page. Current page is: #=this.dataSource.page()#"
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

Updated to include the definition of `dataq` as per OP and added a `pageSize` attribute to prevent nulls in paging of grid.

This [Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UtOQE/4) example works fine for me (with both of the formats specified in your question)?

**EDIT 2 - solution found**

After continuing our discussion further, it came to light that `dataq` contained the entire response from the controller function. Therefore you needed to access the `responseText` from `dataq` and, because it is a `JSON` string, you need to perform [`JSON.parse(dataq.responseText)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) in order to extract it into a list of objects suitable for the datasource of the grid.

Comment: it didn't work, if I just put the data as part of a script it renders correctly, but if I pass it as a parameter, then no, the console displays this error "e.slice is not a function"

Comment: Well then your data is not being passed to the function in the same format as you posted in your question. Use console to view what `dataq` is when executing `OnCompleteMethod` and edit your question.

Comment: There is no difference for me using one dataset or the other? I included a dojo example.

Comment: I tried your example before and it worked for me when I copied the data inside the <script>,but not when I pass the information from the controller returning a JsonResult

Comment: I updated the Dojo example to include a `schema.model` definition. Can you try this and if still no success, try removing the `Json()` around the data being returned from the controller as well. And if still no joy, post up an image of what `dataq` contains in the `OnCompleteMethod`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144474/discussion-between-heinrich-and-sandman).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try building the grid by using the grid htmlhelper in the razor code instead of a javascript function.

You can reference [Ajax binding in the Telerik documentation here](http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/binding/ajax-binding).

Basically, if the population of the grid is the only thing you need the Ajax for on that view, then you don't even need that "using" specification.  Instead, it'd be specified in the grid configuration.  Similarly, you don't need the javascript code either...your grid in the view's razor could look something like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<BptSearch>()
     .Name("search-results-grid")
     .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .Read(read => read.Action("PermitSearch", "[controller]"))
      )
      .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(job => job.jobID).Title("Job ID");
              columns.Bound(job => job.jobName).Title("Job Type");
          })
      .Pageable()
      .Sortable()
   )
```

If no results are displayed, the "No records to display" message is shown within the pager (this is by design).

This [Grid FAQ](http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq) might be a good reference for you as well if there's other things you want to do with it.

Comment: actually I am trying to not use Kendo Helpers, did you know what it is causing my error in the javascript?

Comment: Looks like in your javascript you need to remove the "[" from after "columns:", and add a comma after the closing "}" before "dataSource".  If that doesn't do it for you then I'm not sure.  Why not use the html helpers?

Comment: I generally find that you get more control over all aspects of Kendo control through using Javascript instead of the helpers. That's just my opinion though.

Comment: Also, the wrappers are not free - you need a purchased license.